# Why am I getting this error when adding columns to my SQLite table?

Tags: android

I have made one program of SQLite having two columns. It runs perfectly. After I added other columns same as above having same table, I got an error. Why did this happen?

Stack trace:

```
03-08 09:16:59.570: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(247): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
03-08 09:16:59.621: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(247):     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mb.demo/com.mb.demo.DemoActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table table1 has no column named logitude: , while compiling: insert into table1(name,address,logitude,latitude,contact)values(?,?,?,?,?)
03-08 09:16:59.621: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(247): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
```

Comment: The exception says it all, `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table table1 has no column named logitude: , while compiling: insert into table1'. The column you think you've added is not actually added in the database. BTW, how you added the column?

Comment: yes but why same created table  can't we  use ?

Answer (score 2):

This is surprisingly like a question I just answered here:
[SQLite Database (why do this?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228353/sqlite-database-why-do-this/5228457#5228457)

If you add a column to a table in the onCreate() method, you'll have to upgrade the database version OR delete the user data for the app in order for the onCreate() to actually fire. Otherwise, your app runs, sees a database with by that name already, and the same version (with the table having only 2 columns), and skips the onCreate(), so your table doesn't get re-created, and your insert fails.

EDIT: another possibility is that your 'logitude' typo has caused an issue. If the table column name is spelled correctly as 'longitude', your insert will fail as noted above.