# SQLite Database (why do this?)

Tags: android

hi i am create a simple SQLite database in android.

i use the SQLite helper class

```
package com.and.example.helper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydata10.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "mytable10";

    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private Context context;
    private SQLiteStatement insertStm;

    private static final String INSERT = "insert into " + TABLE_NAME + "(name,latitude,longitude,address,contectno) values(?,?,?,?,?)";


    public DatabaseHelper (Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context);
        this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        //db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +TABLE_NAME);
        this.insertStm = this.db.compileStatement(INSERT);

    }

    private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, letitude REAL, longitude REAL, address TEXT, contectno INTEGER)" );
        }

        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

            Log.w("Example", "Upgrading database, this will drop table and recreate");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);
        }

        public OpenHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        }
    }


    public long insert(String name, double latitude, double longitude, String address, int contactno){
        this.insertStm.bindString(1, name);
        this.insertStm.bindDouble(2, latitude);
        this.insertStm.bindDouble(3, longitude);
        this.insertStm.bindString(4, address);
        this.insertStm.bindLong(5, contactno);
        return this.insertStm.executeInsert();
    }

    public void deleteAll(){
        this.db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
    }

    public List<String>selectAll(){
        List<String>list = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor cursor = this.db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{"name","latitude","longitude","address","contectno"}, null, null, null, null, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                list.add(cursor.getString(0));
                list.add(cursor.getString(1));
                list.add(cursor.getString(2));
                list.add(cursor.getString(3));
                list.add(cursor.getString(4));

            }while(cursor.moveToNext());

        }
        if(cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed())
        {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

My main Activity class

```
package com.and.example.database;

import java.util.List;

import com.and.example.helper.DatabaseHelper;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DatabaseDemoActivity extends Activity{

    private TextView textout;
    private DatabaseHelper sqlHelper;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        textout = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);

        sqlHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        sqlHelper.deleteAll();

        sqlHelper.insert("Durgesh",1.352566007,103.78921587,"ahmedabad",942974);
//        sqlHelper.insert("Mukesh");

        List<String>names = this.sqlHelper.selectAll();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Name in Database: \n");
        for(String name : names)
        {
            sb.append(name + "\n");
        }

        Log.d("Example", "name size - " +names.size());
        this.textout.setText(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

and i run this project then generate a error Logcat

03-08 09:16:57.963: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1003): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 09:16:57.963: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1003): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.and.example.database/com.and.example.database.DatabaseDemoActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table mytable10 has no column named latitude: , while compiling: insert into mytable10(name,latitude,longitude,address,contectno) values(?,?,?,?,?)
03-08 09:16:57.963: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
03-08 09:16:57.963: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-08 09:16:57.963: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-08 09:16:57.963: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-08 09:16:57.963: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-08 09:16:57.963: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-08 09:16:57.963: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-08 09:16:57.963: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 09:16:57.963: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-08 09:16:57.963: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-08 09:16:57.963: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-08 09:16:57.963: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-08 09:16:57.963: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1003): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table mytable10 has no column named latitude: , while compiling: insert into mytable10(name,latitude,longitude,address,contectno) values(?,?,?,?,?)
03-08 09:16:57.963: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
03-08 09:16:57.963: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
03-08 09:16:57.963: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
03-08 09:16:57.963: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
03-08 09:16:57.963: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:36)
03-08 09:16:57.963: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1145)
03-08 09:16:57.963: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at com.and.example.helper.DatabaseHelper.(DatabaseHelper.java:31)
03-08 09:16:57.963: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at com.and.example.database.DatabaseDemoActivity.onCreate(DatabaseDemoActivity.java:23)
03-08 09:16:57.963: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-08 09:16:57.963: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-08 09:16:57.963: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1003):     ... 11 more

then i solve the error

db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, latitude REAL, longitude REAL, address TEXT, contectno INTEGER)" );

and run the project but generate the same error in LogCat.

and then i change the only database name and table name other code is same and successful run project.

my Question is 
Why do like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't drop the existing tables by upgrading the database version or clear the user data, the table won't get created without that 'letitude' typo you had in the initial creation of the table.

Clear the user data, or drop the table in the onCreate() method, and it'll get re-created with the correct column name.

> and then i change the only database
>   name and table name other code is same
>   and successful run project.

This is b/c if you change the db name, it will go through the onCreate() method since there is no db by that name in the users' data.

Also, please post back with follow up questions if these answers don't help you. If they solve your issue, please click the checkmark to indicate your approval.